# Send a route and markers to render on the Google Maps web site

Tags: google-maps

I have a route directions url that I can send to google maps https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=Aljezur&destination=Porto&waypoints=Odemira|Cercal|Sines|Ermidas+do+Sado|Lisboa|Peniche|Caldas+da+Rainha|Tomar|Leiria.

The thing is that I would like to draw the route and also highlight the nearest gas stations of that route at the same time. Then, the user would navigate the route or get more info about each gas station.

It seems impossible to send a route and query google places at the same time, in the same URL.

Any ideas on how this is done, but without a customised map control?

Than you very much guys

-G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This revealed to be impossible with Maps URLs.
I'm now using customized Maps Javascript API app and it is OK.
Thanks